# maximizing $v^tAv$ by choosing $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $N\times N$ real matrix. $A = A^T$
and Let $v \in R^n$ vector $\left \| v \right \| = 1$

Thus, $v^tAv$ is actually a real number.

The question is beings asked:  how to chose $v$ in order that $v^tAv$ to be maximize ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is too ambiguous. If for example $A$ has an eigenvector $\psi, \left \| \psi \right \| = 1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda > 0$, you could take $v = k \psi, k \in \mathbb{R}$ and the result would be $\psi^T A \psi = k^2 \lambda$. As $k$ is arbitrary, a maximum does not exist. You have to impose a constraint to the problem like $\left \| v \right \| = 1$.

If $A = A^T$ and you impose $\left \| v \right \| = 1$, you have to take $v = \psi_{\text{max}}$ where $\psi_{\text{max}}$ is the unit eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question.I hope you can add more details - how are you sure that there is no other vectors that bring higher results ? also , why the constraint $A=A^t$ needed

Comment: Symmetric matrices have a set of orthonormal eigenvectors $\psi_1, \ldots, \psi_n$ spanning $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you write $v$ as a linear combination of these eigenvectors, i.e. $v = \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i \psi_i$ you should be able to see why. Alternatively, you could use the result from continuous optimization that a necessary condition for $x$ to maximize $x^T A x$ is that the Lagrangian $L = x^T A x - \lambda x^T x$ is minimized, i.e. $\nabla L = 2 \left( A x - \lambda x \right) = 0$ so $v$ satisfies $A v = \lambda v$ for some $\lambda$, i.e. it is an eigenvector.